# Converting ER to relations

Tags: mysql

I have two entities orders och pallets.
Order has a primary key id.
pallets also has a primary key palletID.
We have 0..1 on order sider and * on pallets side.
how should i covert this to tabels in the database?

Comment: You have two tables Orders and Pallets. Each table has a unique ID and there is a many-to-one relation between Pallets and Orders?

Answer (score 1):

To model the scenario where an order may have zero or more pallets, and a pallet may be associated with 0 or 1 orders:

denormalized:

```
orders
------
orderId   (PK)
pallets (e.g. palletA, palletB, palletC, ...)   <--- horrible compound field

pallet
------
palletId  (PK)
```

Put the denormalized tables in the second normal form by adding a FK into the `many` side of many-to-0 or 1 relation, and remove the compound field from the `1` side.

```
  orders
 --------
  orderId   

  pallets
  --------
  palletId  
  orderId (FK)
```

In this model, each pallet references an order (or maybe its null), and many pallets may reference the same order.

Another option is to use a join table. This enables a many-to-many relationship between orders and pallets and keeps the relationship modeling separate from order and pallet data.

```
 orders
 --------
  orderId   (PK)

  pallets
  --------
  palletId  (PK)

  orderspallets
  -------------
    orderId  (FK)
    palletId (FK)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. If you choose the first model, then an order may have 0 or more pallets, a pallet may be associated with 0 or 1 orders.  If you want to find all pallets for an order `select o.orderId, p.palletId from orders o join pallets p on o.orderId=p.orderId`. If you want to include orders with no pallets make it a `left join`. If you want to find pallets not associated with any order do `select * from pallets where orderId is null`.

Comment: The second model above, with the `orderspallets` join table will capture any relation between orders and pallets. An order may have zero or more pallets, a pallets may be associated with zero or more orders.

Comment: zero or one order. a pallet is associated with one or zero order.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it'll get you started.